# Delete single column from primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates, primary-key, multiple-columns

I have a table with a primary key that consists of 5 columns. I found out that one of these columns should not be in the primary key because it is creating duplicates. I'm trying and failing at removing this column (both from the primary key and just entirely from the table).

Initially I just used MySQL Workbench to unselect the column as PK and just clicked Apply. The workbench generates this SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`mytable` 
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`);
```

This causes the following error:

```
ERROR 1062: Duplicate entry '624634475-17-2-19000' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I'm guessing that the database doesn't like the existence of duplicate entries. So I did some searching on how to delete duplicates and found this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE (column1, column2, column3, column4)
```

This query also fails with an error:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '624634475-17-2-19000' for key 'column1'
```

I don't care which duplicate survives, I just want my primary key to be correct and to have some data left over at the end.

Comment: "one of these columns should not be in the primary key because it is creating duplicates" - It seems your problem is just the other way around: *Removing* the column from the PK creates duplicates. (*Adding* a column to an already unique key can make it only "more" unique but never cause duplicate keys where there were none before.)

Comment: @Hanno Binder: Yeah the language is a little strained. There are records in the table which from a functional point of view are duplicates, but they are allowed because the primary key doesn't consider them duplicates. By removing the column from the primary key the database's definition of duplicate will be the same as the functional definition.

Comment: Ok, think I got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't care which duplicate survives, I just want my primary key to
>   be correct

If your new PK consists of columns 1 through 4, and columns 1 through 5 are unique at the moment, you can can use

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, MIN(column5)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, column4
```

to get exactly *one* record for each unique combination of columns 1...4.

Then you can go ahead and delete all records from `mytable` where the (old) PK does not match the values selected above.

After that, columns 1...4 will be unique and you can re-create your PK constraint.

Comment: Yeah that looks like it works too, I'd still need to wrap it in a DELETE query. Can't go deleting individual records by hand; the production database is just too big. Perhaps a DELETE FROM table WHERE NOT EXISTS ( your select here ); ?

Comment: Personally I like the DELETE query I found cleaner and easier to understand, but I can't go around giving myself points for answering my own question.. :)

Comment: Yes, the `WHERE NOT EXISTS ( your select here )` approach was what I had in mind. Maybe using a temporary table. But your `DELETE` seems more elegant anyway (+1) :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You can delete records from a table by comparing the records to each other in this way:

```
DELETE t FROM table t, table u WHERE t.column2 < u.column2 AND t.column1 = u.column1 AND t.column3 = u.column3 AND t.column4 = u.column4 AND t.column5 = u.column5;
```

In this query column2 is the one I want to delete while the other 4 columns are the ones I want to keep in the primary key. All records that are equal in the new definition will be deleted except for one.

Once done I was able to successfully run the original ALTER statement.